# Quarkus Annotation-Based Interceptor with Non-Optional Arguments

Tags: java, interceptor, quarkus

This seems to be a hot topic based on the amount of questions asked but I have not found the answer I am looking for just yet. I want to implement a simple authorization service in my Quarkus app, but I seem to be repeating code over and over again.

Basically, I take in the JWT from the Authorization Http header and check if the role supplied in it is sufficient to access my endpoint:

```
public void someApiCall(@Context HttpHeaders headers) {
    authService.validate(ApiToken.SOME_API_CALL, headers); // Throws an exception when unauthorized
    
    //…
}
```

Now, I think this looks really clunky and I do not like the additional parameter that I need for every single Http endpoint. I have done some research into AOP and know how to add an interceptor which could validate the Http headers through an annotation which would be applied to my method:

```
@Authorize
public void someApiCall(/*…*/) { /*…*/ }
```

The issue is, I do not know how to pass in arguments into this annotation to specify the required role. I want something like this:

```
@Authorize(UserRole.SYSADMIN)
```

This seems pretty simple but I cannot figure it out. Below you will find the interceptor and annotation classes (Missing the required role of course):

Authorize.java

```
@Retention(value=RUNTIME)
@Target(value=METHOD)
public @interface Authorize {}
```

AuthorizeInterceptor.java

```
@Interceptor
@Priority(3000)
@Authorize
public class AuthorizeInterceptor {

    @Inject
    AuthorizationService authService;

    @AroundInvoke
    public void validateRole(InvokationContext ctx) {
        authService.validate(ApiToken.ALL, ((RestEndpoint)ctx.getTarget()).getHttpHeaders());
    }
}
```

RestEndpoint.java

```
public class RestEndpoint {

    @Context
    HttpHeaders headers;

    public HttpHeaders getHttpHeaders() { return headers; }
}
```

SomeResource.java

```
public class SomeResource extends RestEndpoint {

    @GET
    @Authorize
    public Object someApiCall() {
        /* do code directly */
    }
}
```

So, in conclusion, where I write `@Authorize`, I want to have `@Authorize(UserRole.SOME_ROLE)`.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is there a specific reason you do not use one of Quarukus's existing solutions, e.g. [JWT RBAC](https://quarkus.io/guides/security-jwt)?

Comment: That's a good suggestion. I'll definitely take a look at that. My question is aimed at general purpose, so I'll leave it up.

Comment: It also requires the `@Context SecurityContext context` as a parameter to every method call, so I don't think that would be an ideal solution either.

Comment: You only need the `SecurityContext` if you want to access, for example, the token. If you only want to pull out the roles, the `@RolesAllowed` is sufficient. You can take a look at the [Quarkus Security Guide](https://quarkus.io/guides/security).  It lists two other options to work with JWTs (OAUTH2 RBAC and OIDC).

Comment: More good suggestions! Thanks! Do enterprises use these libraries or do they usually write their own?

Comment: This I cannot say. As of now, we use quarkus only internally. Also, Quarkus is relatively young, so not many comapnies use it.

Comment: That's an excellent point. I guess if something works, it doesn't really matter whether it's common practice or not. I'm still curious about the original question in any case.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219818/discussion-between-turing85-and-j-lengel).

Answer (score 3):

So, I managed to figure it out. It turns out that it isn't that hard, I just didn't know where to look.

Here are the modified classes:

Authorize.java

```
@InterceptorBinding
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Target({TYPE, METHOD})
public @interface Authorize {
    // Nonbinding is very important. It makes the interceptor fire regardless of the value
    @Nonbinding ApiToken value();
}
```

AuthorizeInterceptor.java

```
@Interceptor
@Priority(3000)
@Authorize(ApiToken.NULL)
public class AuthorizeInterceptor {
    /* fields */

    public Object validate(InvokationContext ctx) throws Exception {
        authService.validate(/* stays the same */);
        return ctx.proceed();
    }
}
```

SomeResource.java

```
public class SomeResource {
    @GET
    @Authorize(ApiToken.SOME_API_CALL)
    public Object someApiCall() { /* implementation */ }
}
```

As Turing85 pointed out, a similar API already exists in JavaEE which implements the authorization functionality in the same way.